# Kivent, is it possible to transform a tmx file to glsl or use a tmx file to create a glsl file?

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using Kivent to create a 2d game and I'm following [this code](https://github.com/kivy/kivent/tree/2.2-dev/examples/13_tilemap). However, on the [yourappname.kv](https://github.com/kivy/kivent/blob/2.2-dev/examples/13_tilemap/yourappname.kv) file, in line 26, the code loads a glsl file. But I only have a tmx file ([tiled map editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/)), so can I transform my tmx file to something that this code can read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLSL is a programming language for writing shaders, i.e. the programs running on a GPU determining **how** things are to be drawn.

The TMX files seem to be some kind of game world definition. In that respect they are things **that** are to be drawn, which is something entirely different.

I didn't dive too deep into that Kivent thing documentation, but it seems it's your responsibility, as a developer, to write appropriate GLSL files for the engine to use.

Comment: For the next googler: The most shader you will need are in the [examples/assets/glsl](https://github.com/kivy/kivent/tree/master/examples/assets/glsl) folder of kivent

Answer (score 0):

I wondered about using tmx files with Kivent and heard about recently added tiled support.  The below resource (many kudos to the author) outlines how to handle tmx with Kivent ->

http://udiboy1209.github.io/2016-08-19-how-to-use-tiled-maps-in-kivent/

It involves cloning the tiled_gsoc_2016 branch in the Kivent repo and installing it, then you can use the kivent_maps module (map_utils method) to parse a tmx file.

```
   # Load TMX data and create a TileMap from it
    map_name = map_utils.parse_tmx(filename, self.gameworld)
```

Comment: Please include the important parts of your link in case it becomes inactive